Wordpress setting api doesn't work, when class initiate another class
I would like to initiate class setting_management to inside class ckasBlog h1 heading and submit button showing. But settings_fields('custom-settings-group'); and do_settings_sections('custom-settings'); are not showing. various way i was try fix this but this is not showing, how to fix this issue. please help me.
class ckasBlog {

    private $setting_instance;

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_menu', [$this, 'custom_settings_menu']);
    }

    public function custom_settings_menu() {
        add_options_page(
            'Custom Settings',        // Page title
            'Custom',                 // Menu title
            'manage_options',         // Capability required to access
            'custom-settings',        // Menu slug
            [$this, 'custom_settings_page']    // Callback function to render the page
        );
    }

    public function custom_settings_page() {
        $this->setting_instance = new setting_management();
        $this->setting_instance->render_settings_page();
    }
}

new ckasBlog();

class setting_management {

    public function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_init', [$this, 'custom_settings_init']);
    }

    // Register settings and fields
    public function custom_settings_init() {
        register_setting(
            'custom-settings-group',        // Option group
            'custom_option_name',           // Option name
            [$this, 'sanitize_callback']    // Sanitization callback function
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'custom-settings-section',      // ID
            'Custom Settings Section',      // Title
            [$this, 'section_callback'],    // Callback function to render the section
            'custom-settings'               // Page slug
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'custom-field-id',              // ID
            'Custom Field',                 // Title
            [$this, 'field_callback'],      // Callback function to render the field
            'custom-settings',              // Page slug
            'custom-settings-section'       // Section ID
        );
    }

    // Render the settings page
    public function render_settings_page() {
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Custom Settings</h2>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                <?php
                // Output security fields
                settings_fields('custom-settings-group');
                // Output setting sections
                do_settings_sections('custom-settings');
                // Submit button
                submit_button();
                ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    // Sanitization callback
    public function sanitize_callback($input) {
        // Sanitize input here as needed
        return $input;
    }

    // Section callback
    public function section_callback() {
        // Optional: Section description or instructions
        echo '<p>Section description goes here.</p>';
    }

    // Field callback
    public function field_callback() {
        // Render field HTML here
        $value = get_option('custom_option_name');
        echo '<input type="text" id="custom_field_id" name="custom_option_name" value="' . esc_attr($value) . '" />';
    }
}

I would like to display setting_management class functionality inside into ckasBlog class. How to do it?
